# HDMI to DP not working

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I have a Toshiba Tecra A50-C-U3E1 (yes I know...) with integrated Intel HD Graphics 520 GPU.

The laptop has external VGA and HDMI (supporting 1080p format apparently) ports and I am currently using one external monitor (HP ProDisplay P202) with a VGA-VGA cable. This is working with the laptop LCD with no issue at all.

I am now trying to connect a second external screen (P202) using the laptops HDMI port. The only cable I have available is HDMI-DP (The monitor only has VGA or DP), but when I plug in and open up the Windows screen properties, the system can detect the screen but cannot send a signal. The screen will scan both ports and the go into sleep mode.

I have tried a second HDMI-DP cable with the same results. I know the HD 520 will support three screens as I have checked the Intel website.

Does anyone have any ideas why this is not working?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does it work with only the HDMI screen and laptop screen? Sounds silly, but I had a similar problem where the default GPU drivers were not understood by windows and another control panel app from the GPU allowed to do what I needed to do.

Answer (score 0):

More than likely the cable/adapter is DP to HDMI and not the other way around.  Most of these adapters are unidirectional, not bidirectional.  You will need to purchase a HDMI to DP adapter.

Comment: The HDMI port is in the laptop and the DP port is in the screen. The cable is simply a cable, there is nothing to suggest there's anything else added to it.